# Generate instrumented gRPC methods

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, grpc

I'm using gRPC, specifically over the C++ language, and I often reach use cases like:

- Log the processing time of each request
- Populate a "history" database with all transactions that occured in a service

My typical way of implementing such requirements, for example the "log request processing time" is:

```
// Protobuf level definition
service SmartHome {
  rpc ChangeVolume(ChangeVolumeRequest) returns (ChangeVolumeReply) {}
}
```

```cpp
// C++ implementation.
class SmartHomeServiceImpl final : public SmartHome::Service {
  Status ChangeVolume(ServerContext* context, 
                      const ChangeVolumeRequest* request,
                      ChangeVolumeReply* reply) override {
     auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now(); // 1.
     //
     // ... actual implementation
     // 
     std::cout << "Request: " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__<< 
               << " duration " 
               << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
                    std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start).count()
               << " (ms)\n"; // 2.
  }
};
```

I'll obviously abstract statements (1) and (2) above a bit better but there doesn't seem to be an easy/streamlined way to avoid the boilerplate here. **Is there a technique/feature/third party library I could use to handle instrumentation of RPC calls?** Even really restricted solutions like the ability to declare an "on_entry" + "on_exit" function would be really helpful.

Comment: There is an experimental (since 2019) API for adding interceptors, would that suffice?

Comment: @Botje Wasn't aware of it, thanks for the tip. I guess it should be enough even though it seems quite "non standard" - the resources that I found hint at the possibility might go away at any point.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite understand the *Populate a "history" database* case. However, the *Log the processing time* case can be easily achieved with RAII.

```
class RequestTimeLogger {
public:
  explicit RequestTimeLogger(const std::string &method) : _method(method), _start(std::chrono::steady_clock::now()) {}
  ~RequestTimeLogger() {
    std::cout << "Request: " << _method
               << " duration " 
               << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
                    std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - _start).count()
               << " (ms)\n";
  }

private:
  std::string _method;
  std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> _start;
};

#define REQUEST_TIME_LOGGER RequestTimeLogger logger(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

class SmartHomeServiceImpl final : public SmartHome::Service {
  Status ChangeVolume(ServerContext* context, 
                      const ChangeVolumeRequest* request,
                      ChangeVolumeReply* reply) override {
     REQUEST_TIME_LOGGER

     //
     // ... actual implementation
     // 
  }
};
```

Comment: That's pretty much what I'm doing at the moment, but I consider it to be a manual approach. From the looks of it, seems like a valid one. Thanks for redis-plus-plus btw, great stuff.